# "noshell" for ssh proxy users

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I like to setup a special ssh user which is **only** allowed to tunnel web traffice through my server. I do not want to make an open proxy. This brings me to my question:

Is there a "noshell" shell for linux system (I use Debian Squeeze) so the user is able to logon but can not enter any command (but not been disconnected like `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` does)?

It only holds the ssh connection so the tunnelling can proceed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssh -N does not require any shell. please test it with /bin/false as shell.